# scylla-server is failing to start

Tags: scylla

After installing scylla server its failing to start with following error message,

Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain scylla[29145]: Scylla version 2.3.5-0.20190417.0e0f9143c starting ...
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain scylla[29145]:  [shard 0] init - Only 476 MiB per shard; this is below the recommended minimum of 1 GiB/shard; terminating.Configure more memory (--memory option) or decrease shard count (--smp option).
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain scylla[29145]:  [shard 0] seastar - Exiting on unhandled exception: std::runtime_error (configuration (memory per shard too low))
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: scylla-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Scylla Server.
-- Subject: Unit scylla-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit scylla-server.service has failed.

-- The result is failed.
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Scylla JMX.
-- Subject: Unit scylla-jmx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd

### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

### -- Unit scylla-jmx.service has failed.

-- The result is dependency.
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Job scylla-jmx.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit scylla-server.service entered failed state.
Jun 04 07:07:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: scylla-server.service failed.

free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1838         179        1038          25         621        1445
Swap:          2048         113        1935

Answer (score 5):

How many cpus do you have in the machine? `lscpu`

I'm guessing 4 cpus since the error is:
`Only 476 MiB per shard; this is below the recommended minimum of 1 GiB/shard; terminating.Configure more memory (--memory option) or decrease shard count (--smp option)`

Go to `/etc/scylla.d/cpuset.conf` and add change to the `CPUSET="--smp 1"` OR (if you are just testing on a dev environment enable developement mode inside `/etc/scylla.d/dev-mode.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work using a 2 CPU, 4 GB RAM setup. Tried 4 CPU / 2 GB with `scylla_cpuset_setup --smp 1`, which should make scylla use only one CPU thread / shard -- did not work for me. Neither did 2 CPU / 1 GB.

I suggest simply increasing your specs a bit. I bought one [VM for about $10 with 100 GB SSD+HDD](http://www.smartape.ru/?partner=141256) -- so it's not that expensive.